# setChecked() method not working in getView() of custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

This is the code of my custom adapter:

```
        public static class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private static Context mContext;
        private static LayoutInflater mInflater;
        // Keep all Images in array
        private static Bitmap[] mThumbIds;
        private static int mViewResourceId, pos;
        private static CheckBox cb;
        // Constructor
        public ImageAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId, Bitmap[] pics) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mThumbIds = pics;
            mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
            mContext = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);
            // ImageButton imageView = (ImageButton)
            // convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            cb = new CheckBox(mContext);
            Drawable background = new BitmapDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
            cb.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
            pos = position;
            System.out.println("Setting checkbox set: "+imageIsDup[pos]);
            cb.setChecked(imageIsDup[pos]);
            System.out.println("Has checkbox been set? "+cb.isChecked());
            cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        imageIsDup[pos] = true;
                    } else
                        imageIsDup[pos] = false;
                }
            });
            return cb;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm setting the adapter like this:

```
GridView list = (GridView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
                    TextView no = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.noOfDups);
                    no.setText("Found " + noOfImages
                            + " duplicates. Please verify.");
                    //list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    dialog.setTitle("Images Found");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    // ImageAndTextAdapter adapter = new ImageAndTextAdapter
                    // (longOperationContext, R.layout.row, imageNames,
                    // imageLocs, thumb);
                    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(
                            longOperationContext, R.layout.row, thumb);
                    System.out.println("No of images:"+thumb.length);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The checkboxes work fine if I click and unclick them. What doesn't work is the `setChecked()` function. Although the parameter is `true` there are no set checkboxes when it's displayed. What is the mistake?

This code was working before, I made a few edits a while back and it hasn't worked since then. I don't remember the edits sadly.

**UPDATE**
Even though there are only 8 images and the `println` messages should only be `16` altogether there are `48`. The first set being only false, the second two sets having the correct `imageIsDup` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `getView` to:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, list, false);
            // ImageButton imageView = (ImageButton)
            // convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.select);
            //cb = new CheckBox(mContext);
            Drawable background = new BitmapDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
            cb.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
            pos = position;
            System.out.println("Setting checkbox set: "+imageIsDup[pos]);
            cb.setChecked(imageIsDup[pos]);
            System.out.println("Has checkbox been set? "+cb.isChecked());
            cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        imageIsDup[pos] = true;
                    } else
                        imageIsDup[pos] = false;
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method to inform the list to refresh the view?

Also, if you are using eclipse, you can view the local history from any file you edit (available from the right-click menu) - maybe you can use this to remember which edits you did, that changed your functionality.

Comment: The file was edited over 3 months ago sadly. I'll try refreshing the list.

Comment: Nope, the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method did nothing. I never used it before either.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting checkbox listener in ImageAdapter class, you can have **onitemClickListener** , which is eventually going to give you **position** which is being selected. So u can update ur **imageIsDup array** from there.

CheckBox is automatically going to remain **checked or unchecked** based on the **updated value of imageIsDup**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if(imageIsDup[pos] == true)
                                  imageIsDup[pos] = false;
                                else
                                  imageIsDup[pos] = true;
                              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Comment: This part already works fine. What doesn't work is the preset values of `imageIsDup`. The `setChecked()` function doesn't seem to have any effect.